# My label's constraints and truncating tail in tableview cell are ruined after scrolling. iOS7 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, constraints

I have custom tableview cell an some labels in it. I set up constraints for height of this labels programmatically like:

```
self.myTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
self.myTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = 45;
```

It isn't rocket science. It looks fine and tails are truncated with "..." in iOS 9 and iOS 8. But in iOS 7 my truncating tails disappears just after scrolling. What might be wrong with iOS7?

Comment: what constraints you have set?

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean?... Just UITextView height which I connected from storyboard.

Comment: i am asking about constrains (autolayout)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this code:

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
    {
        tableCell.contentView.frame = tableCell.bounds;
        tableCell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    }
```